# Using Skyrim Creation Kit, how to have an NPC stopped by a guard?

Tags: scripting, skyrim-modding

I am making a mod using the Skyrim Creation Kit.
At some point in my quest, the Player must steal a statue that I created, then, as soon as it's done, the next stage begins, asking the player to place the statue in Hulda's inventory at Whiterun Bannered Mare.

As soon as I place the statue in Hulda's inventory, the next stage triggers to tell the player to attend Hulda's arrest.

Everything I said above works.

Also, I created an NPC who is Whiterun's guard, and I created a scene, between the guard and Hulda, during the arrest.

My problem is that as soon as I place the statue on Hulda, there is no my guard coming to stop it and Hulda or the other NPCs don't react, when Hulda should be prosecuted for theft, and thrown in jail.

How do I ensure the guard stops Hulda ?